# SKAction.rotate(to : , duration :) resets if angle passes through 0

Tags: swift, swift-playground, skaction

I'm trying to smoothly rotate a crank (self) that always points to the mouse coordinates (Scene.point).

If I try cranking it a full 360 degrees, when zRotation is 0 degrees, it spins a full 360 backwards to  get to the next degree instead of continuing spinning the direction it is supposed to

```
 self.run(
        SKAction.repeatForever (
            SKAction.sequence([
                SKAction.wait(forDuration: 0.1),
                SKAction.run({

                    let angle = atan2(Scene.point.y - self.position.y , Scene.point.x - self.position.x)

                    //this resets at if angle passes 0 degrees
                    let rotate = SKAction.rotate(toAngle: angle - CGFloat(M_PI_2), duration: 0.5)
                    self.run(rotate)

                    //this works
                    //self.zRotation = angle - CGFloat(M_PI_2)

                })
                ])
        ),
        withKey: "New Thread"
    )
```